# Proof of vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

If $S, T$, $U \leq V$, with $T \subset S$.

How to proof that $S \cap (T + U) = T + (S \cap U)$.

Has it got something to do with direct sum?

Comment: $S+T$ is the inner direct sum consisting for all elements $s+t$, where $s\in S$ and $t\in T$. There is no need for $S$ and $T$ to have intersection $\{0\}$ (zero vector).

Answer (score 0):

Take $x \in S \cap (T + U)$, then $x \in S$ and $x=t+u$ for some $t \in T$ and some $u \in U$. Since $T \subset S$, we have $t \in S$. It follows that $u=x-t \in S$, hence
$x=t+u \in T+(S \cap U).$ This shows that

$$S \cap (T + U)  \subset T + (S \cap U).$$

It is now your turn to show that

$$S \cap (T + U)  \supset T + (S \cap U).$$

Comment: Thanks man that really helped, now to prove S∩(T+U)⊃T+(S∩U).  I take  x∈ T+(S∩U), then x= t+(S∩U) for some t ∈T.  Now x-t=(S∩U), that means x-t ∈ S and x-t∈U, am I right so far?  I dont know how to introduce T+U :(

Comment: I did something else let x ∈T +(S∩U), that implies x= x1+x2 ∈T+(S∩U). Where x1 ∈ T and x2 ∈ S∩U, so x2∈S and x2∈U  but as T⊂S    x1∈T before now becomes x1∈S.   So x1∈S,x2∈S   so is it posible to say that x1+x2 ∈S?? if that´s the case then x∈S and x1∈T,x2∈U.  So x=x1+x2 ∈ T+U?  thus x∈S and x∈ T+U, Hence x∈ S∩(T+U)